# Запятые при уточняющих оборотах

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

Необходима ли запятая во втором случае?

Более 15 млн, или 25% российских семей(,) не готовы менять место жительства.

Answer (score 2):

Более корректно выглядит такая запись: *Более 15 млн российских семей, **или 25% от их общего количества**,  не готовы менять место жительства.*

Здесь ИЛИ — пояснительный союз.

Answer (score 0):

Да, там запятая нужна. Это пояснение. Вот несколько примеров из Розенталя:
Кругом всего здания идёт обширный каменный балкон, или веранда, где, в бамбуковых креслах, лениво дремлют хозяева казарм. (Гончаров)
…Это был Александр Тимофеевич, или попросту Саша, гость, приехавший из Москвы дней десять тому назад. (Чехов)
По всей ширине Лены торчали в разных направлениях огромные льдины, или, по-местному, торосья. (Короленко)

Comment: Вы эти примеры руками набираете или копируете? Если копируете, то дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на издание — любопытно, в каком издании они даются с ошибками.

Comment: http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxv.html#sect97

Comment: Спасибо. Скан-копий этого издания я не нашёл, так что не знаю, кого винить — издательство или сайт. В других изданиях нужные запятые стоят.

Comment: Тогда и ‟попросту” во втором предложении нужно обособлять, ведь это вводное характера подачи, как ‟прощего говоря”, ‟короче” и т.д. Но оно не обособляется в других изданиях / сайтах.

Comment: В первом попавшемся издании действительно стоят запятые.

Comment: С этим пунктом сложнее. Правила в данном случае говорят, что выделение **попросту** факультативное и зависит от авторского замысла. Я посмотрел, что в некоторых изданиях действительно стоят запятые. Но в большинстве изданий выделения нет. Самым авторитетным я считаю так называемую *выверенную беловую рукопись*, которая приведена в издании серии "Литературное наследство" (трудно представить что-то более авторитетное, кроме, разве что, самого оригинала рукописи).

Comment: Кстати, цитата из Чехова действительно принадлежит самому Чехову, а вот цитата из Короленко — всего лишь вольный пересказ по мотивам творчества Короленко. Поэтому там нельзя даже авторским замыслом оправдать.

Comment: Какие правила говорят, что обособление факультативно?

Comment: Если произнести без пауз в значении "просто Саша", тогда это не вводное и запятые не нужны. Но можно и выделить как вводное.

Comment: Ну ладно, может быть. Выражения ‟можно просто Коля”, ‟можно просто Саша” действительно являются чем-то вроде этикетных сочетаний.